# Export Twitter followers

Tags: twitter, export-to-excel

Is it possible to export twitter followers of a certain page ( with 40k followers) to an excel spreadsheet? I just need the username.. Bio, location, and website too, if possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried? Show us your code and we'll help get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch twitter IDs of users from "followers-ids" api of Twitter.and then extract the details of all the followers through their twitter IDs with the help of "users-lookup" api of Twitter.